# Need help identify the part in the photos. It is from a 2004 dodge Stratus

Tags: dodge, part-identification, mitsubishi, stratus

A friend of mine had her timing belt break and they said this part in the image needs replacing also.  We want to order it but don't know what it is named and googling isn't working out so well.  The only think i can determine for sure is it isn't the filler or the thermostat housing.

[image: photo 1]  [image: photo 2]

[image: photo 3]

Comment: It does look like part of the cooling system, but I think the only place you might be able to order it is from the dodge parts counter. I'm surprised the mechanic didn't tell you what it is in the first place?

Comment: i think she's got a shade tree working on it.